# Deleting items from an array requires multiple passes to remove them all

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array of ~1200 ruby objects and I want to loop over them and delete the ones with names that contain words or parts of words.

So I tried this:

```
list.each do |item|
  if item.name =~ /cat|dog|rat/i
    puts item.name
    list.delete(item)
  end
end
```

It works, except that it seems to miss some items with names that should match. If I run it again it finds a few more, and if I run it another time it finds a few more. It finds less each time, but I have to run it 3 times in order to delete everything.

Why in the world is this happening?

Comment: You have an array of 1200 objects that you want to delete at run time?

Comment: It's just a script I wrote to cleanup some data I have stored in a yaml file.

Comment: Eventually, you will need a regular expression for this.

Comment: Well, it runs in about 200 ms, and I run it manually when I get a new data file. This script took me a couple minutes to write, and since I'm not going to run it more than once or twice a year, I think it will do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's you modifying underlying collection while iterating over it.
Basically, if collection changes in some way during iteration (becomes empty, gets prepended with a new element, etc), iterator doesn't have a lot of ways to handle it.

Try [reject](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000434) instead.

```
list.reject! {|item| item.name =~ /cat|dog|rat/i }
```

Comment: Awesome! I was about to create a marker array to hold the marked objects and delete them after the loop finished.

Comment: Just so I understand this - Is it happening because the length of the array is changing. So if I delete Item 2 and the loop is about to iterate to item 3, the former item 3 is now item 2 so it skips it?

Comment: @Seth That makes you expect it to be done in two runs. It does not explain why you need three runs, I think. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Seth Documentation doesn't tell us :) But if `array.each` in Ruby is implemented using indexes (which seems logical), that would happen.

Comment: @sawa [cat, cat, cat, cat] -> [cat, cat] -> [cat] -> []

Comment: Amazing, since its just a list, itterating over, and deleting certain elements shouldn't cause an array contraction, should it?

Comment: Reject! is better, but if you had to iterate for some reason, you could iterate in reverse, so you're deleting behind the iteration instead of ahead of it.

Comment: @sln *speculating* Might depend on the kind of list. For array-based lists, it's natural to use indexes internally for iteration.

Comment: #each is not atomic over mutating methods like #delete and they should not be used together unless you like buggy, poorly defined behaviors.

Comment: More on this, including reject via indexes http://www.natontesting.com/2011/01/01/rubys-each-select-and-reject-methods/

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do the same as `reject!` with `delete`:

```
list.delete_if { |item| item =~  /cat|dog|rat/i }
```