# Rails 3 - Remove items belonging to array B from array A

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm starting to play with arrays, but i'm stuck with something that seems **yet** very simple... 
I'm trying to remove x elements belonging to one array from another array. 
 
I've looked at this but .... blocked :
[Deleting items from an array requires multiple passes to remove them all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616411/deleting-items-from-an-array-requires-multiple-passes-to-remove-them-all)

```
a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
b = ["1","3"]
c = a.reject { |i| i =~ /b/ }
```

Well, i'm a bit lot here, thanks!

Comment: do you want to calculate common elements in both array? if so then use c = a & b

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
b = ["1","3"]
c = a - b
```

same as

```
c = a.reject{ |e| b.include? e }
```

Comment: Mouuuuuwwwaaaaahhhhaaaaaaa (<= me shooting myself in the foot).       Thank you, as often, way simpler than i thought ...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify an existing array by removing elements in another array you can use minus equals.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
b = [1, 4]
a -= b
a
=> [2, 3]
```

Also keep in mind that subtracting an array of elements from another array will remove all occurrences of those elements not just the first occurrence.